# How to limit handling of event to once per X seconds with jQuery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, debouncing

For a rapidly-firing `keypress` event, I want to limit the handling of the event to a maximum of once per *X* seconds.

I'm already using jQuery for the event handling, so a jQuery-based solution would be preferred, though vanilla Javascript is fine too.

- [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKx2K/2/) shows keypress firing rapidly without any limiting on the handling
- [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKx2K/1/) implements limiting the handling to once per 0.5 seconds in vanilla JS using `setTimeout()`

**My question is**

1. Does jQuery have an inbuilt way of doing this? I don't see anything in the `.on()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
2. If not, is there a better pattern for doing this in vanilla JS than I've used in my [second jsfiddle  example](http://jsfiddle.net/mKx2K/1/)?

Comment: You might want to consider using keyup instead, unless you have some reason for wanting the repeats.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ http://www.hnldesign.nl/blog/debouncing-events-with-jquery/

Comment: @zerkms thanks, I was really looking to do this in 'pure' jQuery without plugins but that's very helpful - consider promoting to answer so I can upvote!

Comment: @davnicwil: link-only answer is a boring thing and I'm not in mood to rephrase what already is provided in the links :-)

Comment: If all you want the to get the data the user types into a text field, after he has completed typing, you could use 'change' event

Comment: I'm just using keypress as an example of a rapid fire event - this is a generic question about limiting event handling to a certain interval

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Does jQuery have an inbuilt way of doing this?

No.

> If not, is there a better pattern for doing this in vanilla JS than I've used in my second jsfiddle example?

Instead of using `setTimeout` and flags, you can keep track of when the handler was called the last time and only call it after a defined interval has passed. This is referred to as **throttling** and there are various ways to implement this.

In its simplest form you just have to ignore every call that is made within the time of `lastCall + interval`, so that only one call in every interval occurs.

E.g. here is a function that returns a new function which can only be called once every X milliseconds:

```
function throttle(func, interval) {
    var lastCall = 0;
    return function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (lastCall + interval < now) {
            lastCall = now;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

which you can use as

```
$("#inputField").on("keypress", throttle(function(event) {
   $("div#output").append("key pressed <br/>");  
}, 500));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mKx2K/4)

---

As [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) mentions in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177174/how-to-limit-handling-of-event-to-once-per-x-seconds-with-jquery/18177235#comment26632904_18177235), maybe it is not throttling that you need but **debouncing**. This is a similar but slightly different concept. While *throttling* means that something should occur only once every x milliseconds, *debouncing* means that something should occur only if it didn't occur in the last x milliseconds.

A typical example is the `scroll` event. A scroll event handler will be called very often because the event is basically triggered continuously. But maybe you only want to execute the handler when the user stopped scrolling and not *while* he is scrolling.

A simple way to achieve this is to use a timeout and cancel it if the function is called again (and the timeout didn't run yet):

```
function debounce(func, interval) {
    var lastCall = -1;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(lastCall);
        var args = arguments;
        var self = this;
        lastCall = setTimeout(function() {
            func.apply(self, args);
        }, interval);
    };
}
```

A drawback with this implementation is that you cannot return a value from the event handler (such as `return false;`). Maybe there are implementations which can preserve this feature (if required).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mKx2K/6)

Comment: Isn't this throttling? I think debounce means to keep moving the timeout as long as calls are coming in under certain amount of milliseconds and only make one call finally when things settle down. Maybe I have them other way around...

Comment: @Esailija: I think you are right. I thought that throttling would put all calls in a queue instead of ignoring them, but I'm not sure now. Maybe this is a mixture of both?

Comment: Ok it seems it's not throttling and not debouncing either.. according to this explanation http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation :P or maybe it's throttling... argh but it's definitely not debouncing

Comment: It seems to fit with the last example in the visualization. Anyways, I changed the name because it makes more sense.

Comment: A much cleaner way of expressing it, cheers. And I see you also cleaned up my html ;)

Comment: @davnicwil it will help also to determine what your application does because debouncing might be more appropriate. For example I have never needed throttling in js... let's say you send ajax request with each keypress. Then throttling will waste requests while the user is still typing.

Comment: Sure - I kept it general as I wanted to discover general solutions for future use, but right now I'm looking at redrawing a canvas every time an event fires, but want to limit this to avoid hammering cpu/gpu on less powerful devices

Comment: @FelixKling was there a problem with the debounce implementation when it used Date.now ?

Comment: @Esailija: The event was triggered at the beginning of a sequence of events, not at the end of it. See http://jsfiddle.net/mKx2K/7. Maybe there is a way to do it without `setTimeout`, but I currently cannot think of one (it's late, I should sleep ;)).

Comment: @FelixKling doesn't the new debounce impl mean there will be a delay between the event and the function call?

Comment: @FelixKling yes setTimeout is unfortunately unavoidable for debounce I just realized. There is no other mechanism to call it later when things settle down because that by definition means the function is not called.

Comment: @davnicwil: Yes, but if you keep the interval small (~100ms), it won't be noticeable. But it also depends on the frequency of the event (e.g. the average typing speed of a user for `keypress`). You have to try a few values to find a good one.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah ok but just happening to be acceptable because it's a small interval is a bit of a hack ;) Anyway great answer, and thanks for the examples

Comment: @davnicwil: A lot of research has gone into UX and reaction times of humans and every two events that occur within a ~100ms interval between each other are perceived to happen at once. I.e. the cannot be told apart. You might call it a hack or you can call it applied science ;) Anyways, you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do that event throttling as simple as this:

```
$("#inputField").on("keypress", function(event) {
    var now = Date.now();
    var nt = $(this).data("lastime") || now; 
    if( nt > now ) return;
    $(this).data("lastime", now + 500);  
    $("div#output").append("key pressed <br/>");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Record when the last time you processed the event was, and each time you get an event, do a check to see if the interval you want has elapsed.