# Need to trigger an event as footer comes into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a deep page with a deep footer

I want to use some jQuery to trigger an event when the top of the footer comes into view

I have looked and tried using

```
 var scrollTop = jQuery (window).scrollTop();
```

but it just gives the position when you load, and it doesn't change as you scroll

Any ideas please

Comment: `$( window ).scroll(function() { ... });`

Comment: You need to bind it to `.scroll` http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: well, thanks - but I thought the -1 was a bit harsh - we're not all experienced you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my script on this answer: [Pause and play video when in viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866025/pause-and-play-video-when-in-viewport/26866262#26866262)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwhjk232/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inner = $(".inner");
    var elementPosTop = inner.position().top;
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var elementFromTop = elementPosTop - scrollPos;

        if (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < elementPosTop + viewportHeight) {
            inner.addClass("active");
        } else {
            inner.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks - that's helpful, I can see what you are doing