# Correctly handle onFocus and onClick when fired at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building a datepicker which allows people to either click on the input or use tab to show the datepicker's dropdown. Everything works for handling clicks but when I try to add also an `onFocus` listener it interferes with my `onClick` event listener.

It currently fires the `onFocus` and instantly fires the `onClick` which basically causes my dropdown to show / hide immediately when I click on the input. If I however focus the datepicker by tab it works fine.

I currently see two options for fixing, so:

1. How can I make sure that the `onFocus` is only fired if it is focussed by a 
   `tab` or `shift+tab` event.
2. How can I make sure that the `onClick` handler cancels out the `onFocus` call if they both get fired at the same time?

Comment: You could throttle the events - essentially, only act upon a click or a focus event every x amount of seconds or miliseconds - I.e, if the dropdown was opened or closed less than 100ms ago, ignore the next click/focus event. It's not directly related but [this might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177174/how-to-limit-handling-of-event-to-once-per-x-seconds-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I get `Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons.`. It seems that the event is not passed down to the function for some reason when doing this in the constructor `this.handleClick = _.debounce(this.handleClick, 100)`

Comment: Probably has to do with [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). If you do not need the event, you could rewrite your `onClick` handler to not pass it on to the debounced function.