# translating an element goes back to origin place

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I'm trying to make an element moves when the mouse moves in a random 340° direction excluding the 20° of the cursor so the element won't move to the cursor but when I translate It always goes back to the origin place as if there were no translating. here's the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SVG</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg id="m" width="40" height="40">
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
    </svg>
    
    <script>
let m = document.getElementById("m");
let angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 340) * Math.PI / 180;
var timestamp, lastMouseX, lastMouseY = null;

let setCursorPosition = function(e) {

  //mousespeed
  if (timestamp === null) {
        timestamp = Date.now();
        lastMouseX = e.screenX;
        lastMouseY = e.screenY;
        return;
    }
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt =  now - timestamp;
    var dx = e.screenX - lastMouseX;
    var dy = e.screenY - lastMouseY;
    var speedX = Math.round(dx / dt * 100);
    var speedY = Math.round(dy / dt * 100);
    
    timestamp = now;
    lastMouseX = e.screenX;
    lastMouseY = e.screenY;
  //
  
  m.style.transform = "translate(" + Math.cos(angle)*speedX + "px," + Math.sin(angle)*speedY + "px)"; 
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => setCursorPosition(e));
    </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

thanks

also tell me if the implementation of the direction of the element is just like I wanted or no, I have a feeling that it's wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for here, but I played around with you code and I think I got it to behave how you want it to. The first thing I noticed (very minor), was that this line:

```
var timestamp, lastMouseX, lastMouseY = null;
```

should be:

```
var timestamp = null, lastMouseX = null, lastMouseY = null;
```

Otherwise you are not actually setting `timestamp` and `lastMouseX` initially.

More importantly, the reason your element continues to return to its origin is that it's getting very small mouse inputs as you decelerate your mouse so `speedX` and `speedY` are set to low values at the end of each mouse move.

To fix this I added a this line right before your transform command:

```
if (Math.abs(speedX) < 40 && Math.abs(speedY) < 40) return;
```

Also to make the movement a little smoother I also added a [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177174/how-to-limit-handling-of-event-to-once-per-x-seconds-with-jquery-javascript) to your event listener so that `setCursorPosition` isn't called quite so often (reduces jittery movement), and I added a transition in the styles.

```js
function throttle(func, interval) {
    var lastCall = 0;
    return function() {
        let curTime = Date.now();
        if (lastCall + interval < curTime) {
            lastCall = curTime;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}   
      
document.addEventListener("mousemove", throttle(setCursorPosition, 20));
/* ^ replace original document.addEventListener() with this */
```

```css
#m {
  transition: transform 140ms;
  margin: 200px; //just so I could always see it on the screen
}
```

The numbers I used for the min speed, throttle, and transition were purely experimental so feel free to play around with them to your liking.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking your time to do this, actually I moved from this code because someone told me I was doing it wrong now I am playing with this one https://pastebin.com/T8WhBZMA but the circle always stays in its place. thanks anyway

Comment: and thanks for your suggestions, I'm using that throttle